# Possible to svn export and include unversioned files?

Tags: svn, unix, export

I would like to export my code from the working svn copy while including all unversioned files. For example, there are uploaded images/config files etc, that I would like included in the export.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What do you mean by "export"? You can just use `cp -r` to copy the directory tree directly, and then remove the .svn directories afterwards: `find . -name .svn -type d -exec rm -r '{}' \;`

Comment: svn sticks .svn files in each directory that contain version info, I want a clean copy of the directory tree... unless cp -r will ignore those .hidden files? hmm i will try

Comment: I updated my answer to show how to delete the .svn dirs in your copy.

Comment: I ended up just doing a tar -zcvf app.nov27.tar.gz --exclude=.svn app. Your solution would work but I didn't want to remove the original versioning info. Thanks for the tip, though!

Comment: After re-reading your post, I realized that you mentioned "afterwards" - my bad

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's a built in command for that. You could write a script that interprets the output of `svn st` which will output unversioned files `?   marked/with/a/question/mark.config`

Comment: Not a bad idea, but one would think there would be a simpler route?

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is rather old, and is marked as answered. But I found an other way, hope it's useful for other ones 
- Create new folder which stores you exported code
- RIGHT DRAG your source repository to newly created folder. Then you will see interesting context menu can help.

Ref : http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-export.html

Comment: Did you read the question or did you forget the part in your answer where you're supposed to tell him to install Windows and TortoiseSVN?