# Subversion SSH export question

Tags: svn, ssh, export

So I have a project on a remote file system (that I have been editing via ssh). Now I need to copy the project onto my hard drive. I don't really need version control on the project anymore, so this makes me think that I should `svn export` the project. But there are files that haven't been checked in yet, that I need to preserve when I make the copy.

What would be the best way to copy this project onto my local drive?

**Update:** I'm not sure how to do it, but I would like to just copy all the files (using some sort of ssh secure copy command) then worry about the svn stuff later.

**Update:** This is what I ended up doing to copy the project to my local drive:

```
scp -r username@remotehost:/path/to/dir ./localdir
```

Comment: You might find the answer to the following similar question useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810491/possible-to-svn-export-and-include-unversioned-files

Answer (score 3):

Since you have ssh access, I'd use [rsync](http://samba.anu.edu.au/rsync/).

```
rsync -avz --exclude='*/.svn*' user@host:/path/to/checkout /path/to/local/dir
```

Rsync is great for this.  Note also that `user@host:/path/to/checkout` and `user@host:/path/to/checkout/` are different. The former copies the directory, the latter copies the contents of the directory.

Comment: this looked promising but I am running into lots of errors trying to do this.

Comment: What kind of errors? The '-a' flag will sometimes give you harmless errors about permissions.

Comment: Just tested and verified command on my machines and it worked for me. Need more info to help further.

Answer (score 2):

Leave your working copy the way it is. Now you need to recursively remove all the .svn dirs starting from the root dir of you project:

If you're on linux, you can use the following:

```
rm -rf `find . -type d -name .svn`
```

If you're on windows, this should work:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('DIR /B /AD /S *.svn*') DO RMDIR /S /Q "%%G"
```

Make sure to make a backup before trying either of these commands! But I've used both of these  to disconnect from svn successfully before.

Answer (score 1):

svn switch your project to a branch, check in your local changes, then export the branch. You really want to be able to do the export in a repeatable way, so even if you don't need version control on the local copy, make sure the full tree it comes from the repository export.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the easiest possible way, but certainly the most obvious. I'd just `svn export` the current repository to another directory and manually merge in any local changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need version control on the project anymore, why not simply check in your uncommitted changes first, and then do a `svn export`?

Answer (score 0):

If you use TortoiseSVN, you can do Export All from your working folder, copies non-committed files as well.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than exporting from the repository and then manually moving over files that were not checked in, you could just make a copy of your working copy and then remove the `.svn` files that contain the subversion revision information.

On UNIX (Mac/Linux) you can get rid of these easily with this command:

```
find /path/to/copied/project -name .svn -delete
```