# SVN error - how to repair folder

Tags: svn

I've got problem with local copy of SVN folder

```
$ svn up
svn: REPORT of '/svn-xxx/!svn/vcc/default': Could not read chunk size: connection was closed by server (http://127.0.0.1)
$ svn cleanup
$ svn up
svn: REPORT of '/svn-xxx/!svn/vcc/default': Could not read chunk size: connection was closed by server (http://127.0.0.1)
$ svn status
!       .
!       TM
?       newTM/backup
```

I do not want to delete and restore whole folder because it contains many additional, ignored stuff

On another exported copy, with the same server, everything works flawlessly.

How can I proceed with svn up ?

Comment: I am not sure if it is a problem with your SVN folder, it seems like a problem with the server...

Comment: what does `svnadmin verify repos` report on the condition of the repository?

Comment: @Andre - on other copy it works

Comment: @Si - * Verified revision 0. thru * Verified revision 2312., everything ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably go with copying all files as you suggested (voted up)

- Checkout to new folder
- Copy all from old to new without overwriting and without .svn

  ```
  rsync -av --exclude=.svn --ignore-existing old/ new/
  ```

Answer (score 2):

- Rename the folder
- Checkout the folder (`svn co path/to/folder/`)
- Copy files from the old folder to the new one (but avoid `.svn` directories!)
- When everything works: delete renamed old folder

Answer (score 1):

Can you create a patch? That way you could do a fresh checkout and apply the patch.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way would be to use TortoiseSvn.  However, I'm guessing you are on unix.

- `cp` to the new directory from your working copy.
- Delete alll `!svn` folders

Here's a better explanation of my answer [Possible to svn export and include unversioned files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810491/possible-to-svn-export-and-include-unversioned-files)

## Check that all files, and unversioned files are in the exported directory first!!!

### Then...

After you export to another directory you can delete the entire contents of your working copy.  Do a clean checkout to where your working copy used to be.  then copy your exported files over your working copy.